# My UINavigationBar seems to become out of sync with UINavigationController (see gif below)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

When I try to back out of my Navigation stack using either the back button or swiping back from the left side of the screen, the navigation bar changes but does not dismiss the ViewController (or, in the case of swiping, the navbar animation is not interruptible). Please see the gif below.

[image: A demo of the troublesome navigation bar.]

I'm implementing my NavigationController with storyboard. It's just a UIViewController embedded into a UINavigationController. I've tried detaching the UIViewController and reattaching it to a different NavControl, manually embedding it, removing the TabBar controller that was also embedded originally. All of these have led to the same result.

Edit: Also relevant is how I'm pushing these ViewControllers to the nav stack. To present these VCs, I'm just using `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`.

`present(_: UIViewController,animated: Bool)` gives a modal presentation which is not what I'm looking for.

Any ideas as to what would be causing this odd behavior?

Comment: You should add some code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Looking for code to add caused me to figure it out. Editing the post now with what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the following in my rootViewController's viewDidLoad from some earlier experimentation that wasn't being used:

```
// Setting as delegate might not be necessary right now, 
// could become useful in the future?

navigationController?.navigationBar.delegate = self
```

Evidently it did not become useful in the future. Seems like doing this causes the delegate to become responsible for some of the work navBar usually does for free? Removing it immediately fixed the issue.